# Is it possible to schedule a scale of the new data tier SQL Azure Instances?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to schedule a rescale of an Azure SQL Instance ie reduce to "Basic" over night, and then upscale to "Standard S2" during the day?

Thanks

EDIT

I did try using Azure Automation using the Powershell Runbook, however I get the following error:

```
Error: New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext : A network-related or instance-  
specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and 
that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named 
Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open 
a connection to SQL Server)
```

I have provides all of the requested Parameter values. Perhaps I there is a complication with the fact the automation has to run from West Europe and my resources are in North Europe?

EDIT2

Sorted. Need to just specify DatabaseServerName as just the name, and exclude ".database.windows.net". Also Ensure that you create a Credential Asset for the SQLServer and not Active Directory, and use this. So marking again as answer.

Comment: Just run a scheduled task via automation: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Azure Automation to schedule a job to do this all within the browser.

Getting started with Azure Automation:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-create-runbook-from-samples/

Here is a sample script that scales your DB which you can run as a job:https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f

Comment: Thanks for this. I was just curious as to why one cannot set up an Automation Account in North Europe, I have my stuff there, or is it deliberate to run automations from different regions to where one's resources are?

Comment: I cannot get this to work, it is not working for me as an answer. See EDIT to my question which provides error feedback.

Comment: See EDIT2, Found the required tweak to this

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but just make sure you give enough room to scale up complete. Scale up operation appears to be in the order of size of the database, and this is an online operation without downtime.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by running a CloudService Worker Role with a scheduled task which uses the Update Database Azure SQL Rest Operation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/azure/dn505718.aspx

```
private string GetAuthorizationHeader()
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + _aadTenantDomain);

        // If you wanted to show a credential dialog, do this: 
        //result = context.AcquireToken( 
        //    "https://management.core.windows.net/", 
        //    _aadClientId, 
        //      new Uri("http://localhost"), PromptBehavior.Auto); 

        // Directly specify the username and password. 
        var credential = new UserCredential(
            "yourusername@address.com",
            "password123");

        result = context.AcquireToken(
            "https://management.core.windows.net/",
            _aadClientId,
                credential);
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        string token = result.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }


    private void ScaleDatabase(string serverName, string databaseName, string edition, Guid serviceLevelId)
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var header = GetAuthorizationHeader();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", header);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-03-01");

            string url = String.Format("https://management.core.windows.net:8443/{0}/services/sqlservers/servers/{1}/databases/{2}",
                _subscriptionId, serverName, databaseName);

            //string edition = "Standard";
            //string serviceObjId = "f1173c43-91bd-4aaa-973c-54e79e15235b";

            string xmlBody = String.Format(
            "<ServiceResource xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"
               + "<Name>{0}</Name>"
              + "<Edition>{1}</Edition>"
              + "<ServiceObjectiveId>{2}</ServiceObjectiveId>"
               + "</ServiceResource>", databaseName, edition, serviceLevelId.ToString());

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url);
            request.Content = new StringContent(xmlBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
        }

    }
```

You will probably need to add the nuget package: Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

I also found that the edition, although says optional is actually required.

Also, if you're scaling down, make sure the max size of the database is also specified for the required edition. 
A database currently on Standard with a max db size of 50gb, will not allow you to scale to Basic, unless you also set a new max db size maximum of 2gb.